# Convert Text to Time and Calculate Difference Excel

Tags: excel, time

I have a text as 00:02:02:22 where the syntax is hh:mm:ss:ff (hours:minutes:seconds:frames)

I have tried changing the format to time so that I can calculate the difference between two values but I keep getting #VALUE.

I would like the answer in decimal places as 2.43 seconds...

The decimal value is frames which divided by 24. So e.g.

So the difference between 00:02:02:22 and 00:02:05:18 would be 2.83 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of frame codes:

```
Film (24 frames per second)
PAL (25 fps)
NTSC (29.97 fps)
NTSC Drop-Frame
Digital Video (30 fps)
50 fps
60 fps
```

Assuming yours is the first.

With data in **A1** like:

```
11:11:11:10
```

In another cell enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,2)/24+MID(A1,4,2)/(24*60)+MID(A1,7,2)/(24*60*60)+RIGHT(A1,2)/(24*60*60*24)
```

and format this cell as:

[ss].00

[image]

Once the values are converted to true times, values can be subtracted and the differences formatted as you like.

Comment: that was great. Thank you so much for your help.